# Index Match / VLookup a single value from a data frame to a variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vlookup, index-match

I'm looking to create a new variable in python indexed from a pandas data frame... I'd use Index/Match or VLookup for this function in excel.

Table (in the form of a df in python):

```
ID       Date
0        8-18-22
1        7-18-22
2        6-20-18
3        7-04-19
```

I want to be able to plug in an ID and return a Date as a new variable

This seems super simple... but I've searched for hours on how to do this and I can't figure it out.

---------------- EDIT ----------------- 8-18-22 12:37 CST

Based on answers I realized I need to edit this question.

Say my data frame looks like this:

```
     My_ID        DATE
0    0124        8-18-22
1    1456        7-18-22
2    2678        6-20-18
3    3589        7-04-19
```

I want to be able to input "My_ID" and return the DATE. Not the index of the DF number

Comment: map would be a faster option. if you share a reproducible examples, one can provide the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ID column has unique values i highly recommend you making it the Index column.

```
df.set_index("My_ID", inplace = True)

id_1456 = df.loc["1456", "DATE"] #this stores the "8-18-22" in the variable id_1456.
```

Comment: I apologize for the confusion... based on your answer I added an edit to the dataframe in my main question. I'm looking to locate the DATE based off another column (not the row index of the data frame) 

So in the main question - I added the column "My_ID". This is what I'd want to input to get the date.

Comment: I got closer but can't drop the 0.... since this ends up with a series.....

row_number = df[df['My_ID']=='0124'].index.....
found_date = df['Date'].loc[row_number].....

returns =>  0   2022-08-18 (which is a series)

I'd rather it return just the date....

Comment: i Edited my answer, please try again.